# How can I create a regular pentagon and rotate it about a fixed point?

Tags: java, graphics, rotation, polygon

I am currently a college student in a Java class and I have a project due tonight (short notice I know)...

Here is the description:
"In this project, you are asked to write a Java program to draw a regular polygon around a fixed point for a number of times."
The user gives 3 integers... one for the shape type(3=triangle, 4=square, 5=pentagon, 0=circle), one for the radius of the shape if it were inscribed in a circle, and one for the number of times they want the shape to be drawn. The program then should rotate the shape around the center of the window the specified amount of times with each shape evenly spaced. 
For example...
![A square is repeated for 24 times.][1]

I have figured out the code for a triangle and square, but I'm really stuck on pentagon. Every code I've tried won't even draw one pentagon, let alone rotate it 24 times...If anyone could help guide me in the right direction I would really appreciate it!!!

Here is what I have so far... it's pretty rough but its a start!

```
public class ShapeDrawer extends JPanel{

public double x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, y1, y2, y3, angle= 0, changeAngle;
public int radius;
public int amount, item, center;


public ShapeDrawer(int sh, int ra, int am){
    item = sh;
    radius = ra;
    amount = am;
    changeAngle = 360/amount;
    center = (radius+500)/2;

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;


    if(item==3)
    {
        g2d.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);    

        for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++){

                x1 = center + ((radius * Math.sqrt(3)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians((angle+(i *changeAngle)) + 300)));
                y1 = center + ((radius * Math.sqrt(3)) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians((angle+(i *changeAngle)) + 300)));
                x2= center + ((radius * Math.sqrt(3)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians((angle+(i *changeAngle)) + 240)));
                y2= center + ((radius * Math.sqrt(3)) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians((angle+(i *changeAngle)) + 240)));



                int[] xValues = {(radius+500)/2, (int)x1, (int)x2};
                int[] yValues = {(radius+500)/2, (int)y1, (int)y2};
                Polygon tri = new Polygon(xValues, yValues,3);
                g2d.drawPolygon(tri);


            }
    }

    if(item==4)
    {
        g2d.setColor(Color.CYAN);

        for(int i = 0; i<amount; i++)
        {
            x1= center + ((radius*2) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians((angle+(i*changeAngle)) + 315)));
            y1= center + ((radius*2) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians((angle+(i*changeAngle)) + 315)));
            x2= center + ((radius* Math.sqrt(8)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians((angle+(i*changeAngle)) + 270)));
            y2= center + ((radius* Math.sqrt(8)) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians((angle+(i*changeAngle)) + 270)));
            x3= center + ((radius*2) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians((angle+(i*changeAngle)) + 225)));
            y3= center + ((radius*2) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians((angle+(i*changeAngle)) + 225)));

            int[] xValues = {center, (int)x1, (int)x2, (int)x3};
            int[] yValues = {center, (int)y1, (int)y2, (int)y3};
            Polygon squa = new Polygon(xValues, yValues,4);
            g2d.drawPolygon(squa);



        }

        if(item==5)
        {
                g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);

                for(int i=0;i<amount;i++){

                    Polygon pent = new Polygon();

                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
                    {  
                        pent.addPoint((int) (center+radius * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / 5)), (int) (center+radius * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / 5)));

                    }

                g2d.drawPolygon(pent);
                }

        }

        if(item==0)
        {
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);

            for(int i =0; i < amount; i++)
            {


            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: So you've written the code for 3 and 4 but as yet made no attempt at 5?  _"Every code I've tried won't even draw one pentagon"_ -- well, show what you've tried and explain what about it doesn't work.  You may have put in a lot of effort, but we can't tell that from what you've posted, and nobody here is going to write your code for you, especially as it's a homework assignment.  Are you having trouble figuring out the geometry? If so that's not a question for SO.

Comment: Does the assignment expect you to handle an arbitrary number of polygon sides? If so, your code for 3 and 4 sides won't be too helpful. You should think about what the radius and inscribed circle mean and how they can help you solve this problem. EDIT: What I said is true even if you only have to handle up to pentagons.

Comment: @JimGarrison I have been working on the code for drawing the pentagon for a total of probably 4 hours... I understand the geometry of a regular pentagon from a math standpoint, I just have no idea where to start with the code. I edited my post above with something that I tried but I feel like it is totally off base

Comment: @acbabis so should I try to make one kind of universal code that will draw different shapes depending on the number of sides the shape has? Like instead of all of my if statements, run it through one loop, set the number of sides = n and change what the program draws based on n? (I hope that makes sense)..

Comment: @user3281559 All I was saying is that being able to handle any n would help you to solve the problem; but if you think what you said is correct, you're probably right :)